# Convert String to Timestamp in Spark (Hive) and the datetime is invalid

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, timestamp

I'm trying to change a String to timestamp, but in my zone, the last Sunday of March between 2:00 AM and 3:00 AM **does not exist** and returns null. Example:

```
scala> spark.sql("select to_timestamp('20220327 021500', 'yyyyMMdd HHmmss') from *").show(1)
+--------------------------------------------------+
|to_timestamp('20220327 021500', 'yyyyMMdd HHmmss')|
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                              null|
+--------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 1 row


scala> spark.sql("select to_timestamp('20220327 031500', 'yyyyMMdd HHmmss') from *").show(1)
+--------------------------------------------------+
|to_timestamp('20220327 031500', 'yyyyMMdd HHmmss')|
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                               2022-03-27 03:15:00|
+--------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 1 row
```

A solution may be to add one hour between 2:00 AM and 3:00 AM for those days, but I don't know how to implement this solution

**I can't change the data source.**

What can I do?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The official documentation says:

> In Spark 3.1, from_unixtime, unix_timestamp,to_unix_timestamp,
> to_timestamp and to_date will fail if the specified datetime pattern
> is invalid. In Spark 3.0 or earlier, they result NULL. [(1)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/sql-migration-guide.html)

Comment: What version of spark do you use? I cannot reproduce your issue although we seem to be in the same timezone.

Comment: Spark version 2.4.7
Hive 3.1
Scala version 2.11.12

Comment: Would reading the timestamps as UTC solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two different solutions, in both solutions you have to change the String format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:

```
select cast(CONCAT(SUBSTR('20220327021000',0,4),'-',
  SUBSTR('20220327021000',5,2),'-',
  SUBSTR('20220327021000',7,2),' ', 
  SUBSTR('20220327021020',9,2),':',
  SUBSTR('20220327021020',11,2),':',
  SUBSTR('20220327021020',13,2)) as timestamp);
```

```
select 
cast(
  regexp_replace("20220327031005", 
    '^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$','$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6'
) as timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the following dataframe with a column called `ts`.

```scala
val df = Seq("20220327 021500", "20220327 031500", "20220327 011500").toDF("ts")
```

in spark 3.1+, we can use `to_timestamp` which automatically adds one hour in your situation.

```scala
df.withColumn("time", to_timestamp($"ts", "yyyyMMdd HHmmss")).show
+---------------+-------------------+
|             ts|               time|
+---------------+-------------------+
|20220327 021500|2022-03-27 03:15:00|
|20220327 031500|2022-03-27 03:15:00|
|20220327 011500|2022-03-27 01:15:00|
+---------------+-------------------+
```

in spark 3.0 and 2.4.7, we obtain this:

```scala
df.withColumn("time", to_timestamp($"ts", "yyyyMMdd HHmmss")).show
+---------------+-------------------+
|             ts|               time|
+---------------+-------------------+
|20220327 021500|               null|
|20220327 031500|2022-03-27 03:15:00|
|20220327 011500|2022-03-27 01:15:00|
+---------------+-------------------+
```

But strangely, in spark 2.4.7, `to_utc_timestamp` works the same way as `to_timestamp` in future versions. The only problem is that we can not use custom date format. Yet, if we convert the date ourselves, we can obtain this:

```scala
df.withColumn("ts", concat(
    substring('ts, 0, 4), lit("-"),
    substring('ts, 5, 2), lit("-"),
    substring('ts, 7, 5), lit(":"),
    substring('ts,12,2), lit(":"),
    substring('ts,14,2))
)
.withColumn("time", to_utc_timestamp('ts, "UTC"))
.show
+-------------------+-------------------+
|                 ts|               time|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2022-03-27 02:15:00|2022-03-27 03:15:00|
|2022-03-27 03:15:00|2022-03-27 03:15:00|
|2022-03-27 01:15:00|2022-03-27 01:15:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```